# Express Checkout error message: "Security header is not valid"

Tags: api, paypal, checkout

I'm implementing **Express Checkout** in PayPal.

I have no problem with the first two steps, `SetExpressCheckout` and `GetExpressCheckout`. But when I use  `DoExpressCheckout`, I encounter the error "Security header is not valid".

The API credentials are the same!

I've fixed it by changing the `$environment` to `live` in `DoExpressCheckout`. (The difference `$environment` makes is that it'll use `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp/` instead of `https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp`)

But why?

Is there something wrong with `https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp`?

Answer (score 35):

https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp requires different user-accounts than what https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp requires.

The sandbox accounts can be activated at [developer.paypal.com](http://developer.paypal.com)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same error being thrown for the live environment. For me, it turned out there was a trailing space at the end of my API username.... I removed the space and it worked fine.... I'd pasted them into a config file straight from PayPal and must've copied a blank there as well... so if this happens to you, check for trailing spaces! This would've been obvious if the username was hardcoded in a string, but wasn't because it was in a java properties file.

note that you'll also get this error if your credentials are wrong (ie bad username, password or signature). I just had the same issue happen when I pasted in my info to a config file, and had extra characters at the end of my signature by mistake.

Comment: I had this because I used Test Account vs. API Username, which both look similar.

Comment: i am facing the same problem but the problem is that it is working locally but not working in production it is giving "Security header is invalid". I dont know why. Iam using activemerchant.. Can yo help m in that?

Comment: i've only come across these 2 cases. I'd delete both the username and password in your current config file, or code, and try again. If that doesn't work, then I'd manually login to the prod and sandbox using the username and password to be sure they hadn't been changed by someone else. Basically this error means "username and password are wrong" - either by mistake because of the extra character, or because they actually are different. Good luck!

Comment: @brad-parks bless you...you saved me probably hours...I will drink to you :-)

Answer (score 2):

He may not grant permission for checkout. Refer to [this article](https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/paypal-permissions-and-advantages-integrating-permissions-api), apparently down for now but still available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20130512002323/https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/paypal-permissions-and-advantages-integrating-permissions-api).