# Paypal Api Redirection Headers issue

Tags: php, paypal

I am working Paypal with using API.  I am getting error like this. I searched in Google.. i got only one suggestion regarding paypal api credentials. but the below code is working in another server. can anybody tell me what may be the reason.Thanks inadvance

```
        Error : Security header is not valid
        Array
        (
            [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d02%2d10T16%3a09%3a39Z
            [CORRELATIONID] => 6df53789eb1fb
            [ACK] => Failure
            [VERSION] => 76%2e0
            [BUILD] => 9605603
            [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
            [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security%20error
            [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid
            [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        )
```

Comment: have a look at this post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712685/express-checkout-error-message-security-header-is-not-valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following maybe..
- You are in sandbox mode with a live account or vice versa
- You have extra spaces before or after the account credentials

Comment: Thank you soo much... I just updated the class file with paypal mode. two days back i made same mistake, at that time i changed this. today i updated old file in new server. Thanks for your valuble time.

Comment: Its not a problem caught us all out from time to time.